# Imagick doesn't want to work on Wamp 2.5

Tags: php, wamp, imagick

I searched all around the web and in some Stack Overflow tickets to find tutorials to install Imagick on Wamp, but no one could make it works :(

So, for the moment, I've installed :

(All my Wamp installation is x86, on a Windows 7 x64)

- WampServer 2.5 x86 (PHP : 5.5.12, Apache : 2.4.9)
- ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-Q16-x86-dll.exe
- GhostScript (some tutorials ask to install it) : gs919w32.exe

I downloaded Imagick at this url : http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.1/

I took "php_imagick-3.4.1-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip"

Then, I unzipped it and copied "php_imagick.dll" in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext

I copied all the CORE_RL_* files in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin

I checked for my environment variable Path, it contents C:\imagemagick (my installation directory of Image Magick)

I put 'SetEnv MAGICK_HOME "C:/imagemagick" ' at the end of httpd.conf in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf (don't know if it's really useful)

Finally I restarted my computer.

The result is that I can't use Imagick in my code, the "imagick" extension **doesn't** appear in phpinfo(), but it **does** appears active in Wamp menu :
[php_imagick extension appears active in Wamp menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLgN1.png)

Do you know what is the problem ? Thank you !

PS : I forgot mention that I added "extension=php_imagick.dll" in php.ini (just after "extension=php_imap.dll" to keep things sorted)
I also created a MAGICK_HOME environment variable set to C:\imagemagick\modules\coders, and i copied all the CORE_* files into a new "core_backup" directory, as Lionel Chan suggested it. But this doesn't make things work :(

Comment: Have you edited `php.ini` to include the extension? I can see that you are probably following my answer on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223732/phpinfo-not-showing-imagick/36224245#36224245

Comment: Yes I did, I forgot mention it >.<

Comment: I just added the MAGICK_HOME environment variable and copied the CORE_* files into a new "core_backup" folder, but this doesn't makes things work better :/